# Ubuntu LAMP server install issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server, lamp

I've installed Ubuntu server 10.10 on a virtual machine using VirtualBox (I'm running Windows 7 64-bit). I have been following these 2 guides in order to set the system up for web development:

Ref guides [1](http://www.lukeweaverwebdeveloper.com/install-your-own-virtual-lamp-server/), [2](http://jamielesouef.com/linux/installing-ubuntu-server-lampsshftpwebmin-and-phpmyadmin-for-a-newbie/)

Everything installs fine & when I boot I get a message that Apache2 web server is loaded. I can also access the default page described in the [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) through a web browser. But when I get to the part where I am supposed to set a static IP address, I have no `/ect` directory when I use Dreamweaver to connect to the root and the network/interfaces file is blank when I load sudo nano text editor using the console.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to use   /etc  not   /ect

Comment: do forgive me I am slightly dyslexic. I am able to access the /etc directory in through the console now, but is there any reason why it would not be listed in the root through Dreamweaver?

Comment: Dreamweaver is an HTML design application - how can you be using it to try and edit system level files on Ubuntu???

Comment: Depends on how you're trying to connect. Unless your FTP server is severely misconfigured, Dreamweaver won't be able to access your /etc folder. You could connect using Dreamweaver over SSH, however, you probably should just connect using Putty over SSH.

Comment: I use dreamweaver as an ftp client/text editor. I assumed that the client the blog writer was using was similar to dreamweaver's site setup, but I see that I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save yourself all this pain and grab a pre-configured LAMP stack, running on Ubuntu, as a VirutalBox Virtual Machine image from Turnkey. They, give you a pre-installed interface to all these settings called Webmin, which allows you to set-up everything in a browser.

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/lampstack

It's just too easy, especially if you're just starting to get your feet wet with Linux / Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would prefer just to login as root, or use sudo but directly inside the Virtualbox Ubuntu VM. Accessing by console, etc. And do there any changes you need be done to the system. I guess by ftp you wont have later any problem  to edit html/css, or graphic files from your Dreamweaver embedded ftp,  (I'd prefer winscp + some text editor, though) as these would be not system files or folders. Other than that, if you don't find your way around, you can always give it a go to [bitnami virtual machine](http://bitnami.org/stack/lampstack#virtualMachine) for LAMP. There is actually one for Ubuntu 10.10. It might make it easier for you.